# WebSocket, ReactPHP

Tags: php, reactphp

Изучаю вебсокеты, конкретно библиотеку reactphp, в документации масса примеров сокет-серверов, но подключение к сокету идёт в основном через telnet. Пытаюсь разобраться как вывести сообщения, полученные от сервера, в браузер. Но соединение с сервером не устанавливается и я не понимаю в чем проблема.

В консоли браузера выводится следующая ошибка: **Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE**.

Необходимо ли при использовании данной библиотеки прописывать и отправлять ответные заголовки на сторону клиента или библиотека сама их формирует? Не нашёл такие подробности в документации, к сожалению.

Может быть причина в Apache, влияет ли он как-то на работу вебсокета?

Cервер:

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server('127.0.0.1:8080', $loop);

$socket->on('connection', function(ConnectionInterface $connection){
$connection->write('Hi!');
$connection->on('data', function($data) use ($connection){
    $connection->write(strtoupper($data));
    });
});

echo "Listening on {$socket->getAddress()}\n";

$loop->run();
```

Клиент:

```
function message (text) {
    $('#chat-result').append(text);
}

$(document).ready(function($) {

    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");

socket.onopen = function() {
    message("<div>Соединение установлено.</div>");
}

socket.onerror = function() {
    message("<div>Ошибка при соединении.</div>");
}

socket.onclose = function() {
    message("<div>Соединение закрыто.</div>");
}

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    message("<div>" + data.type + " - " + data.message + "</div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Сокет сервер не есть ВебСокет сервер. Используйте Ratchet для этих целей

Comment: какого извращения только не придумают для работы с сокетами. 
Изучай протокол TCP. А не какой то непонятный хайп ВебСокет. Эти все библиотеки просто обертка. Ты никогда не научишься их использовать в полной мере, без знания принципов протокола.